# How to stop a prolog program from continuing when the list is empty

Tags: prolog

So I am learning basic programming for prolog and I have run into a few problems. I am using append in prolog to remove the first X number of elements from the list (X being any random number that I input). The program runs into a problem though when the list is empty and I have asked for more than contained in the list. It should be returning []. 
 ex Input. removable(R,[1,2,3,a],5)

```
removable(A,B,N) :- length(X,N), append(X, A, B).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using `length` and `append` like this. It makes your code iterate through the list a lot.

Instead, try this:

```
removable(0,R,R).
removable(X,[],[]) :- X > 0.
removable(X,[H|T],R) :- X > 0, Y is X - 1, removable(Y,T,R).
```

Please note I've changed the order of your arguments to follow the convention that inputs are on the left and outputs on the right.

Your call would then be:

```
?- removable(5,[1,2,3,a],R), write(R).
```

That outputs `[]`.

Answer (score -1):

In prolog it's better to work with recursion and try to work with Head and tail of the list. You have all three vaiables instantiated so it's not possible for prolog to instantiate a term for example e with  a.

```
    removable(A,B,N) :-
  removable(A,B,N,0). % This is just another call with accumulator.



 removable(L,L,Acc,Acc). %This is your base case, When Acc and Acc will equal then prolog will find one succesive branch.

removable([],[],_,_). %This base case says that no matter what values Accs have if a list is emepty then substitue other also with empty list and return result.

 removable(R,[H|T],N,Acc) :-  %This predicates removes H and keeps counting when removed elements equal to N then first(base case) will succeed.
     NewAcc is Acc + 1,
     removable(R,T,N,NewAcc).
```

.